# Hang-fire only executing one job at a time

Tags: c#, hangfire

We have a scheduled job that running for more than two hours . And now other scheduled jobs is adding as Queued , why Hangfire not running that jobs. I set worker count as 3, but still it not executing.
[image: Job Details]
**HangFire Details:**

Installed on : Windows 2018 R2

Hangfire Version : 1.6.22

DB used : PostgreSQL

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that you are not using filter/attribute which disables concurrent execution, like https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/disable-concurrent-execution-per-queue/4008 ?

Comment: @jbl no , we not using any DisableConcurrentExecution attribute in project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding more info , that may help others .

Later i found out that my scheduled job was running multiple times (in every 30 minutes). And all my 3 worker was executing that single job , and there was no free worker to execute pending jobs.

Looks like this issue is related to this hangfire bug #[Bug:130](https://github.com/frankhommers/Hangfire.PostgreSql/issues/130) , #[BUG:1197](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1197)

this fix is working :

```
new PostgreSqlStorageOptions()
       {
           //change this
           InvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) 
       });
```

But even though i set auto retry to false (by setting Attempts = 0), it was retrying the scheduled job. And it was not even logging that retry even after i setting log event (LogEvents = true). i only got this information only after using this LogEverythingAttribute

```
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0, LogEvents = true, OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Fail)]
```

Is this a other bug in Hangfire ?

i closing this as maybe issue with hangfire .